# Implementing Azure Active Directory Authentication in a client OWIN Web Application

Tags: authentication, nancy, owin, azure-active-directory, katana

Hello I have read and implemented these Vittorio Bertocci tutorials:

["Secure ASP.NET Web API with Windows Azure AD and Microsoft OWIN Components"](http://goo.gl/3y41bb)

["Protecting a Self-Hosted API with Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory"](http://goo.gl/3y41bb)

However unlike the tutorials my web application is comprised of the following OWIN components: NancyFx & ASP.NET Web API  (following the architecture pattern set forth [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx))As I attempt to implement AAD authentication (as Mr. Bertocci does in his tutorials) into my NancyFx module (to authenticate a user who hits a route requiring authentication):

I get the following error

Additional information: Loading an assembly required for interactive user authentication failed. Make sure assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' exists.

clearly the AAD dialog that pops up asking a user to login has a dependency on WindowsForms and shouldn't be invoked from a web application.

What AAD credential prompt should I be using instead?
How to I implement AAD auth in a web app client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of the scenario you are trying to implement is that you have the following actors:

Browser  ->  Web Application  ->  Web API

Where the browser is authenticates a user to the Web Application and then the Web Application attempts to obtain a token that will allow it to access a resource at the Web API on behalf of the user.

That being the case, your Web Application will need to redirect the browser to the AAD OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint.  There the user will enter their credentials and be redirected back to the Web Application with an authorization code.  You can then use that authorization code to obtain a token via the [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/1.0.2).  Specifically you will use the AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode method.  The following blog entry by Vittorio gives more detail on the code you will need to implement in the Web Application in order to obtain the token.  It is not an OWIN specific implementation, but should be easy to translate into your NancyFx app.

[Using ADAL’s AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode to Call a Web API From a Web App](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/29/using-adals-acquiretokenby-authorizationcode-to-call-a-web-api-from-a-web-app/)

You should not have to change your ASP.NET Web API that you implemented per ["Protecting a Self-Hosted API with Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory"](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/12/10/protecting-a-self-hosted-api-with-microsoft-owin-security-activedirectory/?utm_source=feedly)

The version of AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken that is used in the client app example in the [Protecting a Hosted API...](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/12/10/protecting-a-self-hosted-api-with-microsoft-owin-security-activedirectory/?utm_source=feedly) blog entry is intended for a different scenario where no browser is involved.  Instead the user is interacting with a desktop application that is then calling a Web API on the users behalf.  In that case, the AcquireToken call must show a browser based dialog in order to allow the user to sign in and obtain an appropriate token.